# C# forms consume memoria al abrir y cerrar otro formulario

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, manejo-de-memoria

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo un Form principal y al presionar un boton cierro el formulario y abro el secundario, despues abro un tercero con el secundario y para finalizar vuelvo a abrir el primero, el uso de memoria es asendente cada vez que repito mi secuencia.

Form1>>Form2>>Form3>>Form1

Trate con diferentes metodos como:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
this.Hide();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Tambien trate con el metodo :

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
this.Dispose();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Y tambien con el siguiente metodo:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
this.close();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El uso de memoria se ve considerable cuando repito al menos unas 10 veces:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y abria que ver que tienen esos forms, y si realmente estan liberando la memoria.. por lo que se ve ahi, el GC no corrio todavia... corrio 2 veces y ahi libero, pero sin saber mas, imposible decirte que pasa...

Comment: Estas publicaciones podrían ayudarte https://stackoverflow.com/a/2940647/13419694 https://stackoverflow.com/a/27875665/13419694

Comment: Esto también https://stackoverflow.com/a/69253051